# How to enforce start and end date tick labels regardless if it's a major or minor tick?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a timeseries (one of many) ranging between the years 2001 and 2023.

This is how it looks like when I plot it:
[image]

As you can see the major ticks are every 4:th year and the minor ticks are enforced with a `YearLocator()`.

However I would like to display the start and end years (2001 and 2023 respectively) at the ends of the axis so that the reader can immediately (without counting minor ticks) tell which year-range they're looking at.

The range is originally [2001, 2023) - meaning that it's from and including 2001-01-01 to, but not including, 2023-01-01. However, I've tried [2001, 2023] as well, but it made no visual difference.

The code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 6))
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.grid(color='lightgrey')
ax.plot(df.iloc[:, 0], df.iloc[:, 1], label='MSCI WORLD')
ax.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.minorticks_on()
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(YearLocator())
plt.show()
```

I suppose the solution would be, in this case, to set the date tick label on the minor ticks at the ends, but I can't seem to figure out how to achieve that. In addition, the solution needs to work with any date range (in terms of years), and therefore needs to be generic enough.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest predefining the location of xticks and corresponding separately. For example, you can use pandas for doing so. The most important part here is the `pandas.date_range` function. You can set a start date, an end date and a frequency. By setting '4YS', the frequency is four years and the start date of each year is chosen. Later, one needs to add the last year manually if it is not already contained in the 4-year cycle.

First, load the packages, create some sample data and copy what you did.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import YearLocator
import pandas as pd

# Generate some sample data
dates = pd.date_range('2001-01-01', '2023-01-01', freq='D')
values = pd.Series(range(len(dates)), index=dates)

# Create the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 6))
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.grid(color='lightgrey')
ax.plot(values.index, values.values, label='MSCI WORLD')
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
```

Now, we generate the list of years for the labels and finish the adjustment of the plot.

```
# Generate a list of all years for labels
year_list = list(pd.date_range(dates[0], dates[-1], freq='4YS'))
year_list.append(dates[-1])

# Set the major tick locations and labels
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator(4))
ax.set_xticks(year_list)
ax.set_xticklabels([date.strftime('%Y') for date in year_list])

# Enable gridlines at major tick locations
ax.grid(which='major', axis='x')
plt.minorticks_on()
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(YearLocator())
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, however you've hardcoded the frequency to 4 years. I have multiple timeseries with different date ranges and therefore different frequencies. I therefore would require a more dynamic, general solution. I will edit my question to clarify this.